# How to convert loop to list comprehension in Python - specific puzzle

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This code, if you give it a number N, it generates 1234...N or N...4321, but produces the output not as a string, but rather as a number.  I wanted to convert the loop in the middle into a list comprehension but ran into trouble trying to do it.

Here is the code that works (written in Python 2.7:

```
def findTens(N):
    # counts number of tens in a number: examples:  
    #   * 100 & 113 would both return 2
    #   * 9 returns 0
    #   * 14 returns 1

    incrementer = 1
    while True:
        if N - 10**incrementer < 0:
            break
        else:
            incrementer += 1

        if incrementer == 100:  
            break   # debugging condition
    return incrementer - 1

def create_seqNum(N, reverse=False, showWork=False, returnDescr=False, divLength=100):
    '''create_seqNum() --> iput N, and get back a number built from the sequence of 1234...N
Arguments: reverse=True to get the sequence in revers, showWork=True to see numbers that add up to final,
returnDescr=True to print the answer in a sentence as well as returning it as a number.'''

    num = 0
    tensIncr = 0
    answer = 0
    Ntens = findTens(N)
    modifier = 0            # modifies counter when increment of 10 occurs
    if reverse == True:     # create range builder inputs
        rstart = 1
        rend = N+1
        rinc = 1
    else:
        rstart = N
        rend = 0
        rinc = -1
    for i in range(rstart, rend, rinc):
        itens = findTens(i)
        num = i * 10**tensIncr        
        tensIncr += 1 + itens
        pad = (Ntens - itens)
        if showWork == True:
            print(("For %d" + " "*pad + " Add: %d") %(i, num))    
        answer += num

    if showWork == True:
        print("#"*divLength)

    if showWork == True or returnDescr == True:
        print("Answer: %d" %answer)
        print("#"*divLength)

    return answer
```

These test cases all work with the above code:

```
for i in [1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 107, 1012]:
    create_seqNum(i, reverse=True, returnDescr=True)
    create_seqNum(i, returnDescr=True)
```

Note too that my attempt to create working list comprehensions broke down both for retiring the loop in the calculation and for making it possible to get the list of numbers it added up as well as the final sum (the "showWork" option).  But if no one cracks them both, then the best solution to the calculation that passes all tests will be accepted.

In case it helps - Here is my attempt to convert it to list comprehensions that failed.  If anyone can figure this out, looking to learn from your answer and thought others might find the puzzle of this interesting (at least I hope):

```
def create_seqNum_v2(N, reverse=False, showWork=False, returnDescr=False, divLength=100):
    '''create_seqNum() --> iput N, and get back a number built from the sequence of 1234...N
Arguments: reverse=True to get the sequence in revers, showWork=True to see numbers that add up to final,
returnDescr=True to print the answer in a sentence as well as returning it as a number.'''

    num = 0
    tensIncr = 0
    answer = 0
    Ntens = findTens(N)
    modifier = 0            # modifies counter when increment of 10 occurs
    if reverse == True:     # create range builder inputs
        rstart = 1
        rend = N+1
        rinc = 1
    else:
        rstart = N
        rend = 0
        rinc = -1

    workList = [i * 10**((i-1) + findTens(i)) for i in range(rstart, rend, rinc)]
    answer = sum(workList)

    if showWork == True:
        # [ print(("For %d" + " "*(Ntens - findTens(i)) + " Add: %s") %(workList[i], i)) for i in workList ]    
        # [x for ind, x in enumerate(list1) if 4 > ind > 0]
        [print(("%d" + " "*(Ntens-findTens(x)) + ": %s") %(ind, x)) for ind, x in enumerate(workList)]

    if showWork == True:
        print("#"*divLength)

    if showWork == True or returnDescr == True:
        print("Answer: %d" %answer)
        print("#"*divLength)

    return answer
```

Source and background of this Challenge:

On HackerRank, they have you solve the N = 123...N by simply not using strings and they accept a simple one line print format statement as the answer.  While using python 3.x print arguments in connection with unpacking a list is a lot more efficient to solve this, I became interested in whether you could build the number, as a number without doing any string conversions at all to do it.  Since `print()` I think converts to string under the covers before it outputs content, I felt this was a more interesting approach, from a purely academic standpoint.

Comment: What does `findTens` do?

Comment: counts number of tens() in the number fed into it.  I will add that function shotly so you have it.  Must have forgot.

Comment: Do you have to use the `create_seqNum` function?

Comment: where the learning value is in this particular exercise is in figuring out the challenge of converting the logic in the loop with something comparable as a list comprehension.  There are many ways to solve this and I am sure many experienced programmers will come up with better ways.  The original challenge this was taken from specifically stated "no strings" or "string functions" to create the answer.  See notes at end of the post on the background for more info.  This is just for the learning.  This is not a production exercise.

Comment: The tricky part of directly converting that loop into a list comprehension is the `+=` statements. List comps work best in stateless contexts where the results of a previous iteration don't interact with the calculation of the current iteration. A useful intermediary step might be to write the loop without using any assignments that depend on variables that still have values from the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: tricky?  Yes.  Not even sure this one can be done.  Posted to see if someone out there can crack it.  Your suggestions are interesting.  Not sure if they are possible within the context of what this code does.  If an answer is found, it should be most interesting.

Comment: see my new answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single line (minus importing), in no more than O(n) steps, without writing separate functions or loops, just a standard map-reduce.

```
import math # to get math.log10
listofints = [1,2,3,10,12,19,99,100,101,50102030]
n = reduce(lambda x,y:[x[0]*(10**(y[1]+1))+y[0],0],map(lambda x:[x,int(math.log10(x))], listofints))[0]
print(n)

# the number 1231012199910010150102030
```

This uses a standard [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) method to adorn numbers using map, and then reduce them back to a number.

The first step:

```
map(lambda x:[x,int(math.log10(x))], ...
```

takes a list of integers like:

```
[1,2,3,10,12,19,99,100,101,50102030]
```

and converts them into a list of pairs that are the number plus it's base-10 logarithm:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [10, 1], [12, 1], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
```

Then, the next step is to reduce that list down to a single number:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:[x[0]*(10**(y[1]+1))+y[0],0],...
```

In order to do that, you need to multiply it by enough powers of ten to make room to add the next number on. Luckily, the next number says how big it is. So multiply pair one's number (the first part) by 10 to (one plus) the power of the next pair's power (the second part), and then add in the second pair's number (the first part).

The reduction looks like this as it goes:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [10, 1], [12, 1], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[12, 0], [3, 0], [10, 1], [12, 1], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[123, 0], [10, 1], [12, 1], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[12310, 0], [12, 1], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[1231012, 0], [19, 1], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[123101219, 0], [99, 1], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[12310121999, 0], [100, 2], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[12310121999100, 0], [101, 2], [50102030, 7]]
[[12310121999100101, 0], [50102030, 7]]
[[1231012199910010150102030, 0]]
```

Finally, the last item is [1231012199910010150102030, 0], so take it's first element, which is 1231012199910010150102030

### UPDATE

While the whole map-reduce thing is a good process to get used to, it was overkill here. This can be done without map entirely, just using reduce:

```
n = reduce(lambda x,y:x*(10**(int(math.log10(y))+1))+y,listofints)
```

Comment: I especially like the detailed explanation picking this apart.  Going to take some time to pick this apart as and test it but i can see in your write up that your testing is even more extensive than mine.  :-)  `math.log(x,10)` could literally replace `findTens()` in my code (a` while` loop).  That this condenses the calculation down to a single loop-less line makes me realize I probably should have phrased the question that way instead of specifically asking for list comprehension, but just out of curiosity I may see if I can integrate your logic into one.  Thanks so much for this write up.

Comment: That works.  Tinkering some more just for the learning.  Do you still have the line or lines of code you used to generate the look indicde reduce?  If so, I'd like to see it.  (you can post here or edit the answer with it, whatever is easier).  Thanks.

Comment: i updated this to use math.log10 instead - that seems to fix the issue. it's a floating point rounding issue. it now works for [999,1000,1001,9999,10000,10001,99999,100000,100001,999999,1000000,1000001] and even [999999999999999999999999,1000000000000000000000000,1000000000000000000000001]

Answer (score 0):

Uh, so, this looks like cancer but I think it works

```
def get_seq(n):
    return sum([(m+1)*10**(m + [sum([k/10 for k in range(n)][:i+1]) for i in range(len([j/10 for j in range(n)]))][m]) for m in range(n)])
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to "build the number, as a number without doing any string conversions at all to do it"?

Comment: and then print the number?

Comment: yeah gimme a sec, it seems possible

Comment: you misunderstood the original question.  The question is to use logic that builds a number rather than string and uses numbers to do it.

Comment: nvm one sec, need to fix it a bit more. There's some unnecessary parts too

Comment: I will test this soon and get back to you.  My initial attempt was simpler but only worked for 0 to 9 (like one of the answers on here).  Then I built the loop and did some other tests and tried to convert it but mine failed. Ugly is not a crime if it works. :-)  Will let you know.

Comment: Not sure your intent, but was testing it on Python 2.7.  I think 5 works.  1 seems to get trapped in either an endless loop or a really long one.  Will restart and try again tomorrow in case it is just something random.  Even though 5 worked fine in a quick test, this loop (which I removed 1 from) to test it on multiple numbers also froze tonight:  `for i in [5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 107, 1012]:
    print(get_seq(i))`  but i want to do more testing to understand which cases don't like it (if possible).

Comment: One additional thought:  will vote for answers that work but if anyone does it, will accept the answer that finds a way to preserve the way the loop version provides ability to view the inner workings to see what numbers were added up before they were summed.  Doing that and doing list comprehensions is more challenging.  If no one does it, then I'll accept the best answer that at least solves functionality and works with all test cases.  Thanks so much for sticking with this after the initial comments exchange.  More hopefully tomorrow or later this weekend.

Comment: Turns out, one of my locked up attempts finished running.  It failed for 98 and the bigger test cases.  I chose these tests knowing that right at the tens is where things can get wonky (the change over for needing an extra zero for each output number used in the summation or it all goes to crap).  I feel like it if makes it through 10's , 100's, 1000's ... that's good enough for me and stop testing there.  :-)  Sorry to bring the bad news about the results though.  I can see you put work and thought into developing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm understand your problem, but are you looking for something like this?

```
def create_seqNum(num, reverse=False):
    final_num = 0
    x = [x for  x in range(1, num+1)]
    y = [y for y in range(num, 0, -1)]
    for i in range(0, num):
        print(x[i], y[i])
        final_num += x[i]* 10**(y[i]-1)

    return final_num
```

Comment: I added test cases to question that can help highlight where this breaks.  In my tests: reverse and forward produce the same answer, but that's easily fixed later,  The return value is actually zero but it prints answers that work for smaller test cases.  It starts to fail completely in terms of the answer it produces around 10.  Thanks for working on this though.  If you run the code from my loop version against test cases you will see it seems to handle anything (though admittedly, I felt like testing around ones, tens, hundreds, and a quick thousand case was enough.

Comment: The goal is to find a way to retire the loop with list comprehensions but admittedly, this is looking very challenging so thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood but what about:

```
def msb(N):
    return sum(((i+1)*10**i for i in xrange(N)))
```

and

```
def lsb(N):
    return sum(((i+1)*10**(N-i-1) for i in xrange(N)))
```

This fails if N >= 10, though.

Comment: Oh, your lsb(N) is nicer than my forwards(N)

Comment: My first attempt also only handled 1 to 9.  Looking for something that  can work on larger numbers too (part of the challenge).  FYI, my 1 to 9 formula looked like this:  `answer = sum([i*10**(N-i) for i in lst])`.  I put the range in a list first so I could add the showList feature to it.  I hadn't tested reversing on that version yet.  Thanks for contributing this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def reverse(N):
    return sum([(x + 1) * 10**x for x in range(N)])

def forwards(N):
    return sum([(x+1) * 10**y for x, y in zip(range(N), range(N-1, -1, -1))])
```

Comment: Modified the test cases to work on yours like this:  `for i in [1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 107, 1012]:
    print(reverse(i))
    print(forwards(i))` (just posted the test cases minutes ago, so sorry they were not there when you worked on this.

Comment: 10, reversed works, but forward produces this output: `1234567900`.  Both look like they start messing up with my 11 and higher test cases.  This really is a more challenging one than it probably first appears.

Answer (score 0):

This only holds for 1<=N<=9, but one can note that the square root of numbers of the form 1234...N...4321 are N ones.

```
def seq(n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, [1]*n)**2/10**(n-1)
```

Comment: `reduce()` is something I have been meaning to tinker with but see comments on other posts.  The loop version can handle much wider tests cases (some test cases are now included with the question).